# LDAP support in krb5-server package

Tags: kerberos

I wanted to find out whether there is ldap directory support in the kerberos packages.I want to  install kerberos5 and ldap as provider.I do not want to install the directory server 389 is offered.What is a possible solution to this problem.
Any help will be appreciated.
Ok Thanks

update:My question might seem ambiguous but I want to find out whether MIT kerberos5 rpm packages have LDAP support,so that I can use ldap as backend for kerberos5 principals data.The krb5kdc shows the following result.

```
ldd /usr/sbin/krb5kdc:   linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff77dff000)
libkadm5srv_mit.so.8 => /usr/lib64/libkadm5srv_mit.so.8 (0x00007f7608e15000)
libkdb5.so.5 => /usr/lib64/libkdb5.so.5 (0x00007f7608c03000)
libgssrpc.so.4 => /lib64/libgssrpc.so.4 (0x00007f76089e2000)
libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00007f76087a0000)
libkrb5.so.3 => /lib64/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007f76084c2000)
libk5crypto.so.3 => /lib64/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00007f7608296000)
libcom_err.so.2 => /lib64/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00007f7608093000)
libkrb5support.so.0 => /lib64/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007f7607e88000)
libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib64/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00007f7607c84000)
libresolv.so.2 => /lib64/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f7607a68000)
libselinux.so.1 => /lib64/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f7607848000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f7607643000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f760728b000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f760706e000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003542200000)
```

This output shows no ldap support.I want to install kerberos5 with ldap.I would like to find out if it is possible to do this and not use the 389 directory.I have no experience with 389 directory.The same package in ubuntu is named as krb5-kdc-ldap which is quite obvious.
Thanks

Comment: Please go to serverfault.com.

Answer (score 0):

What I  really was looking for turned out to be  packag "krb5-server-ldap",this is where the ldap schemas for Kerberos are stored.But what I especially want to mention is the brilliant stuff about Kerberos,ldap,NFS in this blog [Kerberos+ldap as backend](http://itdavid.blogspot.com/2012/05/howto-centos-62-kerberos-kdc-with.html).I would recommend everyone looking for kerberos 5 plus ldap information to read this material.It has saved me hour of work.Very precise and right on target.

The second best I think is the Ubuntu official help site.
[Kerberos ldap help](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/kerberos-ldap.html)

Good Day